# Disabling "Sign In " tab on startup

Tags: google-chrome

No matter that

- in *Settings* → *Basics* → *On startup*, I have selected *Open the home page*
- *Home page* is set to my internal address

Chrome still opens with two tabs: my *Home page* and a *Sign in* tab (in foreground!).

How do I disable this *Sign in* thing?  I do not ever want to use it.

The version I'm using is Chrome 18.0.1025.168.  (For purposes of testing, I'm intentionally using older version.)

Comment: On the Sign In page (under the form with credentials) there is a link to skip it. Once pressed, the Sign In page does not show up again on next start-ups.

Answer (score 21):

Open the "Preferences" file from your profile* and edit the "sync_promo" section. This might look something like:

```
(...)    
   "sync_promo": {
      "startup_count": 6,
      "view_count": 4
   },
(...)
```

In this section, add  `"user_skipped": true` (don't forget the comma at the end of each line that is not the last in the section), like:

```
(...)    
   "sync_promo": {
      "user_skipped": true,
      "startup_count": 6,
      "view_count": 4
   },
(...)
```

Find the information in [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-xYpQgNxG0). So, thanks to Vlăduţ Frăţiman.

- profile path: open `chrome://version/` 
  or `C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` in Windows 7.  You can use Notepad to edit it.

Comment: Make sure Chrome is closed before you edit the file. Otherwise your changes will be overwritten when Chrome closes.

Comment: The sync_promo line should look like this: "sync_promo": { "startup_count": 1, "user_skipped": true

Comment: Some (deleted) answers suggest one might also need the same line in a `"sync"` section. Like `"sync": { "user_skipped": true, "suppress_start": true }, "sync_promo": { "startup_count": 3, "user_skipped": true }` But I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 13):

in *Settings* → *Basics* → *On startup*, choose *Open the following pages* and put this link

```
chrome://newtab
```

Comment: @krispy - But only works if you want static home pages. For me I want it to be where I left off without the annoying additional page.

Comment: @MartinSmith - very good point

Answer (score 4):

This has been bugging me for a while and it appears Google is encouraging people to sign in.

I needed to make another tweak for anyone who has had this problem recently.

Script before:

```
"http://www.google.co.uk/" ]
   },
   "sync": {
      "suppress_start": true
   },
   "sync_promo": {
      "startup_count": 3,
      "user_skipped": true
   },
```

Script after fix:

```
"http://www.google.co.uk/" ]
   },
   "sync": {
      "user_skipped": true
      "suppress_start": true
   },
   "sync_promo": {
      "startup_count": 3,
      "user_skipped": true
   },
```

Works for me.

Comment: Please don't write anything chatty like "Google wants to have our data for their big plan". Just answer the question. Please read [help] before answering or asking. Thanks.

Comment: (Hmmm, @user99572isfine, as for your suggested edit: I wanted to hit "improve" to also get some code formatting in there, but clicked "approve" instead. I guess you cannot edit either at this point?)

Comment: Actually, this seems to be a comment [to prometoy's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/432822/disabling-sign-in-tab-on-startup/479279#479279). When reading the suggested help, you'll see you need just a bit of reputation to be able to comment next time.

Comment: More like browbeating people into submission by interrupting their workflow every ~ 30 mins. The best solution is to switch browsers as they keep changing the setting name to push new ways to get this tab in your workflow again.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes sign in page appears at every startup because you installed
an extension that needs to communicate with your google account.

for example "[Google Keep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?hl=en)" ask you to sign in because it saves favorite links in your google account.

It is better to first check installed extension. `chrome://extensions`

Answer (score 2):

Just click on the "No, thanks" link at the bottom of the sign in page.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why you should open any file and skript around within... thanks

Comment: I don't see any such option https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFje.png

Comment: Google removed this option and instead chose to make the browser useless by having it interrupt your workflow every few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Run `chromium-browser --bwsi` to ["browse without sign-in"](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and disable it.

Comment: OP is running chrome. Does this also work with vanilla chrome?

Comment: "...and disable it."?  The Q is that I don't know *how to disable it*.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!

Privacy and security >Sync and Google Services> turn off “Allow Chrome sign-in”

This stops the constant new tab prompt to sign in every time you open chrome, I

think this happens when we use chrome apps like drive or keep etc.