# Chrome prompts for sign in on startup

Tags: google-chrome

I just installed Chrome on a new laptop and now every time I start Chrome the first page that appears is a Google sign in page. The url in the address bar is -

```
chrome://signin/?source=0&next_page=chrome%3A%2F%2Fnewtab%2F
```

My home page is set to www.google.com but this Sign in page still shows. How can I get rid of the sign in page and get www.gooogle.com as my startup page?

Comment: IIRC, there should be a button on that Sign-In page that says "Skip for later" or something related. Once I clicked it no longer prompted me to sign in. I can't remember the exact details, so I'm offering this as a comment instead. :)

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is not signing in to a Google account, you can just skip the sign in process, [as explained here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824).
If the sign in request still comes up, clear your Google related cookies and cache and try again.

Comment: This looks like a dup of http://superuser.com/q/432822/121091